# How to remove the white space between GridLayouts in RecyclerView?

Tags: android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am trying to make a 2 column GridLayout in RecyclerView. Each item in the grid is an ImageView. I have got the RecyclerView working, but the resulting GridLayout has massive white spaces between the columns. Here is an image of what it looks like. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance!

[GridLayout-RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Wnn.png) 
Code from xml layout used to inflate the views in the RecyclerView

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_movie_poster"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/test" />
```

Code from main activity

```
 private void setRecyclerView() {
    mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(MainActivity.this, mMovieData);
    mPopularMovieRV.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2,
            GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);


    mPopularMovieRV.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    mPopularMovieRV.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(0));
}
```

Code from my Adapter

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder>{

private MovieData[] mMovieDatas;
private Context mContext;

public MovieAdapter (Context context, MovieData[] movieDatas) {
    mContext = context;
    mMovieDatas = movieDatas;
}

@Override
public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_image_list, parent, false);

    MovieViewHolder viewHolder = new MovieViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindView(mMovieDatas[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMovieDatas.length;
}




public class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView mMoviePoster;

    public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mMoviePoster = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_movie_poster);
    }

    public void bindView(MovieData movieData) {
        // TODO use picasso to download image.
        String posterPath = movieData.getPosterPath();
        String fullPosterPath = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/"
                                + "w185"
                                + posterPath;

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(fullPosterPath).into(mMoviePoster);
    }
}
```

}

Code from my ItemDecoration

```
public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private int space;

public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
    this.space = space;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                           RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.left = space;
    outRect.right = space;
    outRect.bottom = space;

    // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
    if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) == 0) {
        outRect.top = space;
    } else {
        outRect.top = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you solve it?? I can't figure out how to delete the white space

Comment: Hi Coeus. I did manage to find a work around. So what I did was: Go to the layout xml file that u use to define how each item within the recycler view will look. So in my RecyclerView there's just 1 image. I made sure the ImageView is match parent in both width and height. And then I tick the adjust ViewBounds. That way, when I run the RecyclerView, there are no more white spaces.